# Mathjax is producing numbered breaks between content in Rmd github_document

Tags: r-markdown, mathjax, github-document

When I render the following Mathjax within an Rmd github_document I am getting undesired numbers between lines of my formula. How can this be suppressed?

```
$$
\begin{align}
\text{converted}_i & \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n=1, p_i) \\
\operatorname{logit}(p_i) & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{condition}_i, \\
\beta_0 & \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-5, 5) \\
\beta_1 & \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-5, 5) \\
\sigma & \sim \operatorname{Exponential(1)}
\end{align}
$$
```

Desired output

[image]

Actual output

[image]

Comment: I don't get numbers.  Maybe you've got something earlier in the document that turns them on?  Posting a complete document (not the real one, just enough to illustrate the issue) would help.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't use LaTeX -- `github_document` is HTML output, so it's using MathJax, which is only approximate LaTeX.

Comment: try using `\beign{align*}` and `\end{align*}` instead.  That should remove the equation numbering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` suppressed the numbering.

@Davide_Cervone this is your answer and I am happy to give you credit if you post as an answer.